# evaluateJavascript is not working on Android system webview version 55.0.2883.91

Tags: java, android

```
evaluateJavascript("test();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
       LogHelper.i(TAG, "onPageFinished ----------------------------  value : ", value);                        }
   }
});
```

It's not working in android webview version 55.0.2883.91

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.